# Encrypted REST calls

Tags: reactjs, rest, express, networking

I am currently designing a website that uses a large number of REST calls to a custom API, and I am growing concerned that the sheer number of requests is making it so that anyone looking through the inspector can get a good sense of our backend database structure.

An example is that we have a page with an internal messaging system, with comments below certain notifications, and looking in the inspector you can see all the network data from the server:

```
{"user_id": "12", "first_name": "Joe", "last_name": "Shmoe" ....}
{"user_id": "234", "first_name": "Sally", "last_name": "Jane" ...}
{"comment_id": "234929", "content": "Hey this is a comment"...}
{"reply_id": "2342394", "content": "This is a reply"...}
etc
```

When I look at how other websites are returning REST calls, I see stuff like this (example from Gmail):

```
{
  ...
  3: [["10984146", "76111484146"], "63436418", 3230]
  4: null
  5: null
  6: [null, null, [[[0, "R"]]]]
  7: null
  8: null
  9: null
  10: null
  11: "YA8K6oBg2Tyc3"
  ...
}
```

And they're all like that, and the url is something unintelligible like `/?n=2&ifk=d7&jsver=Bfq68...`, whereas my REST calls look like `/comments?message_id=1234&user_id=234234...`.

I assume part of the cryptic nature of Gmail's REST calls is that they are using server side rendering, but where are the cryptic REST calls coming from?

I'm tempted to convert to using SSR just to limit how easy it is to read all our data coming through, but I feel like that is bad motivation on its own.

So my underlying question is this: Why do major websites have REST calls that look like the second example, and how do I do that?

Comment: Maybe a more important question is what security do you have enabled in both the server and client including authentication, validation, protocol, and similar?

Comment: I use a 3rd party oauth service that grants an access token that the server verifies for each request. Also feel I've done fairly well trying to protect against XSS, SQL injection, use https, etc.

Comment: Okay, so hypothetically what if someone discovers your complete schema of your database. What specific concerns do you have?

Comment: My biggest concern is that I'm coding in the networking equivalent of Webforms (or whatever dinosaur paradigm you choose). I look at more established websites conducting REST calls like the 2nd example above, and don't even know what I'm looking at. Since security is adding layers of deterrents, I feel I'm being careless by exposing the schema, even if I've taken precautions elsewhere.

Comment: So, JSON is convenient, but it's not size efficient as it duplicates lots of field names.  Google may have just designed a format (specific to their app) that is more space efficient.  If it's a danger to you that someone figures out how your client-side Ajax calls work, then you have a serious design problem because anyone can figure that out, even if you change things.  There are no secrets in browser-based client code or in APIs used by the client.

Comment: As an example, instead of sending this `{"user_id": "12", "first_name": "Joe", "last_name": "Shmoe" ....}`, you could send this `[12, Joe, Shmoe]` and then your client-side code would just have to have its own code to parse this and associate data with known fields based on position.  FYI, this doesn't improve security.  It does reduce data transmission bandwidth (which is probably relevant go Google at their scale).

Comment: That makes sense. And fair point about the design. Thank you both for your help!